# AdMob mediation with Facebook Audience Network in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, admob, facebook-audience-network

I have an xamarin forms app with ads from admob. I would like to use admob mediation to show ads from Facebook Audience but it is not working.

I have configured a mediation group in admob and created an account and ad space in my Facebook developer account using this [guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/mediation/facebook) on the admob website. I have also added the following packages to my xamarin forms android project:

```
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite
Xamarin.Facebook.Android
Xamarin.Facebook.AudienceNetwork.Android
```

I can see requests to the Facebook audience network in my admob mediation report however the fill rate is zero and I cannot see any requests on the Facebook developer website.

This is what I see in the Android app logs:

```
[Ads] Trying mediation network: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/...
[Ads] Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.ads.mediation.facebook.FacebookAdapter
[Ads] Trying mediation network: 
[Ads] Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter
[Ads] Server parameters: {"gwhirl_share_location":"1","pubid":"ca-app-pub-..."}
[DynamitePackage] Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
[Ads] Starting ad request.
[Ads] Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("***") to get test ads on this device.
[Ads] Not retrying to fetch app settings
[Ads] Ad finished loading.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the Facebook Audience Network package I also needed to add the Facebook adapter for Admob which can be found [here](https://bintray.com/google/mobile-ads-adapters-android/com.google.ads.mediation.facebook/).

To add this to my xamarin forms project I followed the directions [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/) to bind a .arr file in Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Is it still working ? When using the latest versions (6.0.0) I have runtime issued because the adapter seems to look for an not existing method (setAdListener).